# "Solved" - Form not submitting the file input... *edit* was checking POST instead of FILE

Tags: php, forms, file, submit

i'm getting a weird bug, my form doesn't submit the file inputs, i really dont get why...

I've tested on both local and remote servers.

print_r($_POST) shows every post but there no file there...

the html:

```
<form action="<?php echo $page_link; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="example">
 <label>Titulo</label>
 <input type="text" name="title"/>
 <label>Imagem </label>
 <input name="test" type="file" size = '50'/>
 <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value=""/>
 <button class="submit_btn guardarbutonz" type="submit" name="submit_btn">guardar</button>
</form>
```

the php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_btn']) and $_POST['thisID']=="") {

echo "<script>console.log('".print_r($_POST)."')</script>";
die();

}
```

Comment: That's just it, you're only checking for POSTs and not FILES.

Comment: yeah, i totally forgot about that, i was blindly fixed on the POST

Answer (score 2):

You will find your files via the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) superglobal:

```
print_r( $_FILES )
```